# How does sscanf handle overlapping pointers?

Tags: c

I have the `ia32 assembly` code for a `c` program I'm trying to reverse engineer. In one method it appears to have the line `"sscanf(input_phrase, "%d %c %d", ebp-4, ebp-9, ebp-8);"` (given that input_phrase is a `c` string and `ebp` is a pointer). Given that a char is 16 bits, the space it's storing the char in should overlap with the space it's storing the second int in (and through testing I have found this to be the case). Is there a precise definition for how this code should work or is it unpredictable?

Comment: @nhahtdh A `char` is 1 byte in C, not 8 bit.

Comment: @nhahtdh 1 byte(minimum size 8-bit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the actual question is "it doesn't" - I'm not entirely sure if the specification mentions it, but I'm 100% sure that `scanf` has no concept of "Oh, this overlaps that, so I'll do something different" - you simply get undefined behaviour. The outcome of trying such a thing is entirely unpredictable [it's quite likely that it just results in whatever is read last overwriting whatever it overlaps in the first read - but it could also cause a crash or world war III to break out!]

Fortunately, the code shown doesn't invoke that behaviour, as a `char` in C is defined as having a size of 1, so there is no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

The C standard counts sizes in units of a char, so the size of a char is by definition 1. Unless you're on some strange hardware (signal processor, pdp-10, or something like that) this will also correspond to a normal, 8-bit byte. Since you're on the x86 architecture, you seem to be mistaken about the variables being overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

On x86, `char` will be 8 bits (1 byte) in size. Thus, on the stack, the variables are laid out as

```
CJJJJIIII
         ^ebp
```

where `I` is the first int, `C` is the character and `J` is the second int. There is no overlap.

Comment: A `char` and a `byte` in C has at least 8 bits. C's `byte` should not be confused with a regular 8-bit `byte`, AKA [`octet`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_%28computing%29).

Comment: Yeah, yeah, it's specific to the system. I think it's true for every C compiler on every x86 processor ever, though, so I adjusted the answer.